# Don't load images, css or themes, and scripts in scrapy

Tags: css, image, scripting, scrapy, block

I need to prevent the loading of images, css files, themes, and scripts from a web page. In a basic scraping with scrapy

There is some way to block them from setting.py or another?

import scrapy

```
class MySpyder(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Spiderr'
    start_urls = [l.strip() for l in open("Archive").readlines()]

    def parse(self,response):
        tittle = response.xpath("/html/body/").get('').strip()
        url = response.url
        yield {
            'tittle': tittle,
            'URL': url,
        }
```

I guess that will make the website suffer less

Comment: Please use English in your title.

Comment: open the response in the browser `view(response)` without an internet connection and you won't get any of the script rendering (no further requests will be made), with that being said the scripts you are referring Usually come from CDNs or dedicated servers with only one purpose, so do not worry about them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scrapy use source code only in response

you can check using `response.text`

JS rendering is what you are referring about which scrapy do not apply.

If you want to hit server less you need to add `time delay` and `decrease concurrent requests` from `settings.py`

Comment: I need both methods, reduce the amount downloaded, and the impact on the server

Comment: Scrapy does not load anything except the HTML document source. It will make a single request and come back with a string which can be parsed by the css/xpath selectors. Slow it down and use less concurrency unless you have rotating proxies.